# remove ul from wp nav menu wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nav

I am using twenty thirteen theme. I am using wp_nav_menu to display menu items. I need to remove the container div and ul from wp nav menu. I tried this.

```
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
```

But it's not working. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

add `false` for `container`

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
```

Comment: I've tried:
'container' => false
'container' => 'false'
'container' => ''

None of the above have any affect on the surrounding div or ul.
Is there ANY way to do this without editing the functions.php file?

Comment: @user1380540 what are you trying to do?

Comment: @mark I am trying to do what the title of this question is. I ended up doing it by adding some code to the functions.php file as it seems there is no other way around it

Answer (score 0):

Even this question is quite old, I want to add a working solution. I found this question while searching for exactly the same, but the answer from Mark just removes the container not the ul or li tags of `wp_nav_menu`.

Remove all `<ul>` and `<li>` tags from `wp_nav_menu`:

```
function remove_wp_nav_menu_ul($menu){
   return preg_replace( array( '#^<ul[^>]*>#', '#</ul>$#', '#^<li[^>]*>#', '#</li>$#' ), '', $menu );
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'remove_wp_nav_menu_ul' );
```

Just place that in the function.php of your theme. But before doing so, always consider to solve this with CSS before.

Answer (score 0):

**Below code in `functions.php`**

```
 function remove_wp_ul($menu){return preg_replace( array( '#^<ul[^>]*>#', '#</ul>$#', '#^<li[^>]*>#', '#</li>$#' ), '', $menu );}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'remove_wp_ul' );
```

**Inside `header.php`, write the following code:**

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'mymenu','container' => false,)); ?>
```